# Convert GMT time to IST using formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime, timezone

I have a field ActivityDateTime whose value is 2016-12-08T11:51:00.000Z at backend. On front end value of ActivityDateTime is 8/12/2016 5:21 PM. I have created a formula field "Rescheduled_Date_Time__c" as Text type which has below formula.I wanted it to be in IST. It should return me 5:21 PM but it is returning 11:51 PM .Anything wrong with my formula .

```
IF( 
OR( 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 12, 2 ) ) = 0, 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 12, 2 ) ) = 12 
), 
"12", 
TEXT( VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 12, 2 ) ) 
- 
IF( 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 
0, 
12 
) 
) 
) 
& ":" & 
MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 15, 2 ) 
& ":" & 
MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 18, 2 ) 
& " " & 
IF( 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime - 5.5 ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 
"AM", 
"PM" 
)
```

Comment: FYI the reason they are doing 5.5/24 is because with formulas in Salesforce a day is represented as 1. Three days would be represented as 3. You want to get hours in a days so it would be less than one. Specifically it would be 0.229166. It's always better to have Salesforce do the math because if you rounded to say 0.23 that's a different time than 0.239, when the engine does it you wouldn't need to worry about rounding issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula needs a modification .

When we do **TEXT(DateTime)** field SFDC converts the DateTime to TZ format which is in GMT .

Now to force GMT to IST we add **+5.30** hours to the Datetime which can be done by below formula

> TEXT(DateTime) + (5.5/24)

Now lets modify your logic to use this instead

```
IF( 
OR( 
 VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5/24)), 12, 2 ) ) = 0, 
 VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5/24) ), 12, 2 ) ) = 12 
), 
  "12", 
 TEXT( VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5/24) ), 12, 2 ) ) 
 - 
IF( 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5/24)), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 
  0, 
  12 
  ) 
 ) 
) 
& ":" & 
MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5 /24)), 15, 2 ) 
& ":" & 
MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5/24) ), 18, 2 ) 
& " " & 
IF( 
 VALUE( MID( TEXT( ActivityDateTime + (5.5 /24)), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 
 "AM", 
 "PM" 
)
```

Comment: @mohith-Your formula looks same which i have used. Can u tell me what will be the value of  "ActivityDateTime ". Will it be equal to TEXT(DateTime) + (5.5/24)

Comment: Yes .Sorry it's typo from my end .Yes use 5.5/24 everywhere

Comment: @mohith-It worked fine!